# if timestamp is expired by comparing that to current timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a column(**cradit_end_date**) that it specifies a product is expire or not.
this column have two states :

**0000-00-00 00:00:0** <= this means this product has no expiration date.

**A date (ex: 2014-10-24 10:00:00)** <= this means this product has a expiration date (here almost a month later).

now, how can I get products that are both no expiration date and is not expired ?

Is it possible with PHP or SQL?

(I am using mysql).

```
$result_coupons = mysql_query("select id,title,pic,price,off,fake_sell,cradit_end_date from coupons  where
confirm=2 and status=1 and
shop_id=$row->id ORDER BY id DESC limit 1");
```

Comment: If you're going to compare date/times, consider using timestamps instead of formatted strings.

Comment: I am using timestamps .

Comment: Then how are you getting **0000-00-00 00:00:0**?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/N8Upc.jpg

Comment: Try `WHERE (cradit_end_date=0 OR cradit_end_date > NOW())`.

Comment: I always use [Unix timestamps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) myself, so I'm not 100% sure that'll work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check for multiple states in the single column using an OR operator.

```
 ...
 WHERE (cradit_end_date = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR cradit_end_date > NOW())
 ...
```

Comment: I think OR cradit_end_date > NOW() instead of OR cradit_end_date < NOW()